# How to get the number of rows from a mysql query select command with multiple parameters in php

Tags: php

So the error i get it this  mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home line 80

here is my code

```
}if($action['result'] != 'error'){

        mysql_query  ("INSERT INTO Matching VALUES('$firstName','$lastName','$buddy','$party','$sex','$req_sex','$skill','$req_skill','$phone')");
        $match_buddy= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Matching WHERE Buddytype='$buddy'");
        $numrow_buddy = mysql_num_rows($match_buddy);
        if($numrow_buddy < $party-1)
    {
        echo "no matches";
        }if($numrow_buddy >= $party-1)
        {echo "$numrow_buddy";
        //matching the sex
Line 80     $match_sex= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Matching WHERE Sex='$req_sex' AND First Name !='$firstname' AND Last Name !='$lastName'");
        $numrow_sex = mysql_num_rows($match_sex);

            if($req_sex == 3)
    {       // if they dont care which sex they have move automatically onto skill
            $match_skill= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Matching WHERE Skill='$req_skill', First Name !='$firstname', Last Name !='$lastName'");
            $numrow_skill = mysql_num_rows($match_skill);
```

Comment: There's a few bajillion duplicates of your EXACT error message on this site.

Comment: I first heard the words client side language and mysql 2 days ago, each line of code is a small miracle and I really really looked but i barely know what i'm writing let alone what to look for.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is that you need to use back ticks around a column name (`First Name` and `Last Name`) that has spaces in it. Therefore change

```
$match_sex= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Matching WHERE Sex='$req_sex' AND First Name !='$firstname' AND Last Name !='$lastName'");
```

to

```
$match_sex= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Matching WHERE Sex='$req_sex' AND `First Name` !='$firstname' AND `Last Name` !='$lastName'");
```

Same goes for your second select statement.

On a side note: your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Switch to `mysqli` extension and use parameterized queries.

Other thing to consider: as @bksi said in his answer it's better to calculate the number of rows on db side and return just the number rather than pulling all the data to the client. In addition to that you can use conditional count technique to get all your counts in one go with a query like this

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Sex = '$req_sex' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) numrow_sex,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Skill = '$req_skill' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) numrow_skill
  FROM Matching 
 WHERE `First Name` != '$firstname', `Last Name` != '$lastName'"
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query will return a result resource, or `false` if there was an error.
Try `echo(mysql_error())` after the mysql_query to see what the error actually was.